Limit of Brownian Motion for Infinite Particles
Consider the case where there are infinite particles initially separated by given distance $d$ on a line exhibiting Brownian Motion without collision. After a significant period of time, I would expect the probability density for not finding a particle in a given small location to approach an exponential distribution with the rate parameter equal to the density of particles, i.e. $\lambda=1/d$. My question is, am I modeling this correctly and how would the math lead us to the result?
Let $x_i$ represent each particle, $t$ the time, $d$ the separation distance, and           $\sigma^2t$ the variance at time $t$. Does this limit approach the particle density?
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2t}}e^{-(x_i-di)^2/2\sigma^2t}$$
Edit to add: The Brownian motion is clearly not essential to this problem, only that the variance increases to infinity with increasing time. Perhaps there is a more general theorem relating to this property, which would be acceptable.

I think this can best be shown through a slight variation on the Riemann integral.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2t}}e^{-(x_i-di)^2/2\sigma^2t}
&=\frac{1}{d}\lim_{1/\sqrt{t}\rightarrow0}\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp {\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\frac{x_i-di}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2\right)}\frac{d}{\sqrt{t}}\\
&=\frac{1}{d}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{d}=\lambda
\end{align*}

The idea is good but the demonstration is unconvincing: why are you allowed to change the limits?  (The summation and the integral are both double limits and the summation is enclosed by a limit over $t.$)

@whuber This crossed my mind. Analysis isn't my strong suit, but I realized the form is nearly identical to the (improper) Riemann integral. We have a function with partitions at $(x\pm di)/\sqrt{t}$ and can multiply by the width of those partitions $d/\sqrt{t}$ and then sum; the result is the integral of a Gaussian distribution. I am open to a better explanation but this was the best I could conceive after pondering for a few days. (Also, the function evaluated at all limits exponentially approaches zero and is dominated by $e^{-t}$, so I believe it is legit by Tannery's Theorem.)
